# How to decode image with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jpeg

I'm trying to send a jpg image from my page using AJAX with jquery to my server which is handling the image with a php script. I send the image like this:

```
    function post_snapshot() {
      var pic = document.getElementById('snapshot').src;
      if(pic){
        var jpic = JSON.stringify(pic);
        $.ajax({
          url:"picture",
          data: jpic,
          type: "PUT",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(json){
            console.log(json);
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            console.log("Status " + status);
            console.dir(xhr);
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Then I retrieve the image with my php script:

```
private function create_picture($name){
    $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r"); // read pic into string
    $picstr = "";
    while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
        $picstr = $picstr . $data;
    fclose($putdata);

    $picstr = base64_decode($picstr); // decode picture
    if(!picstr){
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "failed to decode image"));
        return;
    }
    $source = imagecreatefromstring($picstr);
    if(!$source){
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "failed to create image"));
        return;
    } else {
        if(!imagejpeg($source,"images/img" . date_timestamp_get(date_create()) . ".jpeg")){
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "failed to save image"));
            return;
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "success"));
        }
    }
```

Currently I get the "failed to create image" message back which means that  imagecreatefromstring() is failing.

My suspicion for why it is not working is because I use JSON.stringify in my javascript which might not play nicely with php's decode function. It also might be in how I am using jquery's AJAX call.

I printed out the decoded string in php just to see what it looked like:
`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgDh[...]`

Does anyone see anything glaringly wrong?

Comment: Isn't the problem the `data:` part infront of the actual image data? Try to decode the input using `$json = json_decode($picstr, true)` then doing like this: `$picstr = base64_decode($json['data']);`

Comment: same as for underscore's comment, it decodes the string to data:image/jpg... so then I trim off the "data:" part and send it to imagecreatefromstring($trimmed) but it still gives the error

Comment: Let us know the result of `fopen("php://input", "r"), true`

Comment: For some reason it's not making the assoc array. We get an error when trying to get $picstr['data'] : Illegal string offset 'data'

Comment: @underscore, I get the error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in [the php file]

Comment: so  `var_dump(fopen("php://input", "r"))` is ?

Comment: "resource(3) of type (stream)↵"

Comment: can you try `file_get_contents` instead of  `fopen`

Comment: it's data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS[...]

Answer (score 0):

You should use [json_decode();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
// read pic into string
    $putdata = json_decode(fopen("php://input", "r"), true);
```

Comment: I tried $picstr = json_decode($picstr); then  $picstr = base64_decode($picstr); but it still doesn't work. When I print the resulting string, I get the same string: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A[...]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out why my original method was not working, however I got it to work by a different method.

I'm using a little library called [Webcam.js](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) which I discovered on reading the documentation that there's a built in upload function. I use the upload function and get the posted file on the php side and everything works great!

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], "images/img".date_timestamp_get(date_create()) . ".jpg");
```